# Enumerable derived set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Construct an example of a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ that has enumerable derived set.

My example is that consider a closed bounded subset of  all rationals in $(0,1)$ now it must have rationals as limit point.

And as $\mathbb Q$ is enumerable so it's subset.

Is my approach right?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't have no work in general, because the derived set may well contain irrational numbers and not to be enumerable at all.

A solution would be the set\begin{multline}Q=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac12+\frac1{2^n}\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\right\}\cup\left\{\frac14+\frac1{2^n}\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,2\}\right\}\cup\\\cup\left\{\frac18+\frac1{2^n}\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,2,3\}\right\}\cup\ldots\end{multline}because $Q'=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1{2^n}\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$. Besides, $Q$ is closed and bounded.